# goInstant authentication, ACL, rooms, groups and stuff

Tags: goinstant, goangular

I'm about to write a simple goAngular app for info sharing within heterogeneous cross-domain team (thus I like the idea of ​​using a third party authentication), but I'm still struggling with it. Is it possible to use the "groups" if you use a third-party authentication, or I have to rely on "user-id's?" Who, when and how can modify the array "groups" to control access?

Would anybody be so nice and help me to draft a least expensive access management scheme, where a uniquely identified master user(s) ["google: whatever64"] could manage permissions to other users?

My question is thus wide and general as I believe it must be a mix of code, ACL-tree and database entries(keys).
I will be very grateful for any meaningful advice.

Comment: Unfortunately at the moment you can't restrict access by provider and there's also no way to dynamically change permissions.

This has been identified as a potential roadmap feature, we are currently discussing implementations internally.

Comment: Thank you for the response but it wasn't my point. I'm just struggling to make a master user, that can enrich and manage other .users models (mainly groups). Simply is there any chance how to programmatically say user **google:101283782381919262411** belongs to **Admin** group?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is [Custom JWT](https://developers.goinstant.com/v1/security_and_auth/guides/creating_and_managing_acl.html).  You would then need to update your JWT accordingly.  Both of these processes happen outside of your GoInstant app itself. There are a couple libraries to help you out with JWT's [here](https://developers.goinstant.com/v1/security_and_auth/libraries/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This confirms my belief that [groups] is applicable only for users who are identified by my own domain (custom JWT) and not by a third (public) party like FB or Google.